# What's the right approach for storing and accessing table data in a Redux store

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm very new to ReactJS and Redux (but not development, in general). I'm trying to determine how best to approach a SPA I'm building.

My app will download datasets via API and display them in a spreadsheet. I'd like to use Redux to store the data. Is that the right approach? We could potentially be looking at very large datasets. Would it be more appropriate to only store the data that is currently rendered in the spreadsheet?

I'm totally lost as to an approach that would be efficient in terms of rendering speed and memory management as well as mindful of potential network issues as rows of data are requested from the API.

Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

When you are working on a react/redux app, you generally will have two options to store your state: local component state or in redux. There are quite a few blog posts out there detailing when each is appropriate. [This github issue comment from Dan Abramov](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/1287#issuecomment-175351978), one of the creators of Redux, pretty succinctly sums it up

> Use React for ephemeral state that doesn't matter to the app globally and doesn't mutate in complex ways. For example, a toggle in some UI element, a form input state. Use Redux for state that matters globally or is mutated in complex ways. For example, cached users, or a post draft.
>
> Sometimes you'll want to move from Redux state to React state (when storing something in Redux gets awkward) or the other way around (when more components need to have access to some state that used to be local).
>
> The rule of thumb is: do whatever is less awkward.

Both component state and redux state can be used performantly, so I wouldn't worry too much about that when choosing. From what you've described, the questions I would ask are

- Do I need to have multiple spreadsheets of data loaded, but not all displayed at once? For instance, maybe you have multiple tabs of spreadsheets and you want to be able to tab through them without having to re-fetch the data each time
- Do I need access to the spreadsheet data in a lot of different places, or is it fairly localized?
- Will I be able to modify the data in the spreadsheet, and if so, how difficult would it be to perform those modifications using redux and without?

There are quite probably other considerations as well. In general, the advice given is to stick with just using React local component state until it starts feeling awkward, and then move to redux at that point. Oftentimes, components state is all you need, and if not you'll get a better appreciation for situations where redux helps.